# Controller not getting Initialized until user navigated to the particular url

Tags: angularjs

```
.when("/main", {
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        controller: "MainController"
      })
      .when("/user/:username",{
        templateUrl: "user.html",
        controller: "UserController"
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
```

In User.html i have a button which open a ng-dialog and it has some data from main.html but if the user directly navigated to /user/:username i am not able to render the data from main.html in my ng-dialog.

Comment: That just mean you should put this data into a service and not into MainController. You will be able to store the data into the service and sharing it between MainController and UserController

Answer (score 0):

As per ngRoute, these routes do not have any relation between them. When you move to the route `/user/:username`, MainController is destroyed and UserController is activated.

If you want to have parent child relationship i.e. activate MainController on activation of `/user/:username` route, use **UI Router**.

Code in UI Router would look like:

```
function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .state('home.user', {
            url: 'user/:username',
            templateUrl: 'user.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        });
};
```

Comment: I'm not totally ok with this answer. That would mean that "user" is a sub state of "home" but home and user can be totally unrelated. In my opinion using ui-router would help, but the main part would be to store the data into a service instead of just initialize it into a controller.